# Table will not add with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a table that will enable each cell to turn a color when clicked (like a pixel grid), but i'm having a bit of a difficult time trying to assign the data from a form to a jQuery variable.

I haven't had any problems with any syntax as there aren't any errors thrown up

To generate the table, I don't really know how to do this in jquery, so I just used regular vanilla js instead.

Any ideas?

```js
$(function(){
  var color, height, width;


  function makeGrid(){
    var table = $('pixel_canvas');
    height = $("#input_height").val();
    width = $("#input_width").val();
    color = $("#colorPicker").val();
    console.log(color);
    console.log(width);
    console.log(height);
    for (var i = 0; i<height; i++){
      row = table.insertRow(i);
      for(var j = 0; j<width; j++){
        pixel = row.insertCell(j);
        $(pixel).css({
          'border': 'black solid 1px'
        });
        console.log(pixel);
        $(pixel).on("click", function(){
          $(this).css({'background-color':'color'});
        })
      }
    }
  }

  $("#sizePicker").on('submit', function(){
    makeGrid();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Monoton;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
    margin: 1em 0 0.25em;
}

h2:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

table,
tr,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

tr {
    height: 20px;
}

td {
    width: 20px;
}

input[type=number] {
    width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="input_height" name="height" min="1" value="1">
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="input_width" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixel_canvas"></table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're missing a `#` in your selector: `var table = $('pixel_canvas');`

Comment: What do you mean there are no errors thrown? There's one in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: table.insertRow is not a function`. I assume you know how to use the console since you have `console.log` all over your code?